# VMware Player Internet not working in Ubuntu Host

Tags: networking, 17.04, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 with VMware Workstation 12 Player. I installed Windows 10 as Guest in VMware Player. But cannot make the internet work. Getting the following error,

```
Could not connect 'Ethernet0' to virtual network '/dev/vmnet8
```

VMware Network settings

[image: VMware Network settings]

Tried Bridged and Host-only options, still not working.

My **/etc/network/interfaces** contents,

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

My **ifconfig** output,

```
enp7s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 28:d2:44:34:93:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 815450  bytes 378740719 (378.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 815450  bytes 378740719 (378.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp8s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::3210:b3ff:fe94:91b8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 30:10:b3:94:91:b8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 36388873  bytes 3782447465 (3.7 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 1093979
        TX packets 11323909  bytes 2248899815 (2.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16
```

Can anyone help me to fix this.

Edit:

/etc/sysctl.conf contents

```
#
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
# See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
#

#kernel.domainname = example.com

# Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
#kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3

##############################################################3
# Functions previously found in netbase
#

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable Spoof protection (reverse-path filter)
# Turn on Source Address Verification in all interfaces to
# prevent some spoofing attacks
#net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
#net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable TCP/IP SYN cookies
# See http://lwn.net/Articles/277146/
# Note: This may impact IPv6 TCP sessions too
#net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#  Enabling this option disables Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
#  based on Router Advertisements for this host
#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1


###################################################################
# Additional settings - these settings can improve the network
# security of the host and prevent against some network attacks
# including spoofing attacks and man in the middle attacks through
# redirection. Some network environments, however, require that these
# settings are disabled so review and enable them as needed.
#
# Do not accept ICMP redirects (prevent MITM attacks)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
# _or_
# Accept ICMP redirects only for gateways listed in our default
# gateway list (enabled by default)
# net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
#
# Do not send ICMP redirects (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
#
# Do not accept IP source route packets (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#
# Log Martian Packets
#net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
#

###################################################################
# Magic system request Key
# 0=disable, 1=enable all
# Debian kernels have this set to 0 (disable the key)
# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt
# for what other values do
#kernel.sysrq=1

###################################################################
# Protected links
#
# Protects against creating or following links under certain conditions
# Debian kernels have both set to 1 (restricted) 
# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt
#fs.protected_hardlinks=0
#fs.protected_symlinks=0
vm.swappiness = 10
```

While Running **sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all**

```
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-24-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-24-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1291:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
 LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘LinuxDriver_Ioctl’:
/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1986:1: warning: the frame size of 1168 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
 }
 ^
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-24-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only'
cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-24-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-24-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/smac.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2255:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2256:0: warning: "PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3" redefined
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3 0x07b0

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:73:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3            0x07B0

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/bridge.c:51:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2255:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:73:0: warning: "PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3" redefined
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3            0x07B0

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/bridge.c:51:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2256:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3 0x07b0

  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-24-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-CWgezO/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Blocking file system                                                done
   Virtual ethernet                                                   failed
```

Comment: What do you have in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: @CharlesGreen Added the contents to the question.

Comment: Long ago when I still ran VMWare (I use KVM now), I used to have problems after kernel updates.  These were fixed by running `vmware-modconfig --console --install-all`

Comment: @CharlesGreen Updated with the output of this command. Virtual ethernet fails.

Comment: Which version of VMWare player are you running?

Comment: @CharlesGreen Version **12.5.7** build-5813279

Comment: K - it appears that this most recent version has a couple of new patches which render compiling difficult (here's where I run KVM) - these two links talk about needing to modify a couple of the files, although one is RHEL and the other is openSUSE.  [https://communities.vmware.com/thread/567965](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/567965) and [https://communities.vmware.com/message/2686431#2686431](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2686431#2686431)

Answer (score 0):

Had a chance to reinstall Ubuntu. VMware Player Internet working fine after that. Looks like some issues with network config.

ifconfig results in,

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:1f:56:ce:6b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24  bytes 1632 (1.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 172  bytes 18293 (18.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp7s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 28:d2:44:34:93:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 432343  bytes 111420404 (111.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 432343  bytes 111420404 (111.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.51.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.51.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1990  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vmnet8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.39.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.39.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1991  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp8s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::3210:b3ff:fe94:91b8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 30:10:b3:94:91:b8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3634899  bytes 199331024 (199.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 106167
        TX packets 1116099  bytes 429449640 (429.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16
```

Now network interfaces for vmnet is properly created which failed earlier.